# How do I write an asynchronous C extension to Tcl?

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, tcl

I have a C function that I'd like to make available to Tcl. The thing is, I'd like to make the call asynchronous from Tcl in the same fashion as ::thread::send, i.e. with ?-async? and ?varname? flags.

I do not understand Tcl's asynchronous C API, and cannot find any examples for how to use it. On the C side, I can create a thread to do the work, but then do not know how to signal when the thread is finished, and how to handle the signal to set the variable specified by the varname option passed in the Tcl command.

For this problem, I am not able to use a simpler asynchronous solution from the Tcl side, such as invoking another process with a pipe, Tcl threads, or a library such as comm. The reason for this is that the C call loads in a large data structure, and there are other C calls exposed to Tcl which assume (out of necessity) that the memory for the structure was allocated within the same thread as the Tcl interp.

Any assistance at all will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is write your C code to be synchronous with a simple API, and to keep all its state in `ClientData`-casted structures attached to commands or an interpreter, if possible, or failing that, using thread-specific data. Then, use the Thread package itself to allow other threads to call these utility threads, and wrap that inside Tcl code that makes the API seem natural and which (lightly) conceals just how you go about implementing the API. Which is pretty easy to do.

You could also use Tcl's [C level thread API](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Thread.htm) as the Thread package is really just a wrapper around that. (It *actually* communicates by sending events between threads; check out the definition of [`ThreadSend`](http://core.tcl.tk/thread/artifact/317ee615b233926dd6820a5d5f299aedcde1d68a?ln=2631-2801) in the Thread package for the gory details.) Or, if you're really doing just I/O, you could write your code to use asynchronous I/O and the `fileevent`/notifier mechanism. These are rather more complicated than just doing things the simple way outlined above and using Tcl code and existing packages to do much of the work.

Comment: I don't quite follow the first option. Can I cast state as ClientData and pass a pointer to memory allocated in C between Tcl threads?

Comment: @user374927 That's really not recommended (the passing between threads, that is). Pass the _commands_ between threads; that should be much easier. You _might_ have to pass significant data between threads I suppose, but that's not going to be simple. And is becoming a general C thread handling question (and too outside my expertise…)

Comment: Ah, but the operations upon the structure are graphical, and bound to events in the main thread, so at the end of the day I need a pointer to the data structure in that thread; I can't get by with message-passing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the [TCL Extension Architecture](http://wiki.tcl.tk/327), a.k.a. **TEA**.

Comment: That's useful for _building_ but not so much for _writing_ the code…